# How to Set Specific Heights for a BottomSheetDialog in Android Studio Compose

Tags: android-studio, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khf87.png)I'm currently working with Android Studio Compose and I'm looking to set specific heights for a BottomSheetDialog. I need the heights to be 50%, 75%, and 100% of the full screen height respectively as attached image. Does anyone know how to achieve this in Compose? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to override the built-in module to change specific height ratios, but I encountered an error stating that I couldn't modify variables defined as internal.